# Scripted field does not appear in visualization in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have configured a constant value in scripted field in index pattern in Kibana.
My goal is to set threshold value in the line chart of visualization

[image: scripted field setting]

However, field name "test" does not appear in the line chart of y axis even though I set average as aggregation. The field shows up in discover so setting seems to be all right.

[image]

I have also enabled the script security setting in elasticsearch but still does not work.

```
script.inline: true
script.stored: true
script.file:   true
```

Below is my kibana and elasticsearch version.

```
kibana-5.0.0_rc1-1.x86_64
elasticsearch-5.0.0_rc1-1.noarch
```

Do I have any other setting to enable to use scripted field in line chart?

Comment: could you provide screenshot of y-axis avg aggregation? I can see scripted field but I have 5.0.0 and not rc1-1

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug. I checked that it was fixed in the GA.

Scripted field does not show in line chart of visualize.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/scripted-field-not-showing-in-line-chart-of-visualize/64508